# Custom contact form

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, html

I have a field in the contact form that can contain 2 results, and I would like to send whatever was filled in, I believe that because I use the same name so I do not need to use two "Orders" fields. I believe I have to do a validation.

**Example Pseudo code:**

```
if { 
orders = 1 
send orders
} else { 
orders = null
send orders2
```

**Backend Email Template**

```
<p><strong>Order: </strong> {{var data.order}}<br></p>
```

**Phtml**

```
<div id="pedido" name="pedido" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <label for="pedido" class="required"><em>*</em>Pedido</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select style="height:25px; padding:3px; display: none;" name="order" id="orders"></select>
        </div>
    </li>    
    <li>
        <div class="input-box">
        <input style="width:262px; display: none;" name="order" id="ordertxt" class="input-box required-entry" type="text" />
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

The input is sent normally, only the select is not, I believe that it is because the input is set to value 1, and when it is not filled the code sends null, so I think a validation should be done, that is possible? Would anyone know how to do it? I thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply remove the element via javascript before submit based on this validation.

**e.g.**

```
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function() {
    if(document.getElementById("orders").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("orders").remove();
    }
    if(document.getElementById("ordertxt").value == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("ordertxt").remove();
    }
};
```

So it checks the form with ID of `form` for when it is submitted and then checks values in the fields `orders` or `ordertxt`, if a value is empty the element is removed before form submission. This will allow for you to only send data from a field if it was filled out.

Comment: ha no worries Gustavo